# Connecting UWP app to WooCommerce gives authentication error

Tags: c#, wordpress, woocommerce, uwp, woocommerce-rest-api

I trying to connect **UWP app** to **WooCommerce**.

Found [this plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET)

I write my code like this

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("www.simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_f03bbd67e26a96604ddb188dbd63be3d252891ab", " cs_f8583f42dd1d75da832574b7ad6e649a0687f88f");

WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
//Get all products
var products = await wc.GetProducts();

Debug.WriteLine(products);
```

But I have this error:

[image: Error]

As I understand it is an authentification problem.

Any thoughts, why?

Customer key and secret are correct

Comment: Make sure the key you’re using has write permissions under Users > Profile

Comment: you talk about website? @AndriiKrupka

Comment: yes, try it and let me know bout result

Comment: I will try  tomorrow and will write here@AndriiKrupka

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in WooCommerceNET.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: You need to use the legacy WCObject on the legacy version of WooCommerce Restful API.

Comment: Has this now. I'm regenerate ConsumerKey and Secret @AndriiKrupka

Comment: Could you share the new Consumer Key and Consumer Secret?

Comment: I'm already found solution. Will publish answer @JayZuo-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I have error in permalinks

I found trouble with permalinks, I have this one `/shop/%product_cat%/` and changed it to this one `/product/sample-product/`

And here is code for connecting and get Orders for example

```
 RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");


            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            //Get all orders
            var products = await wc.GetOrders();
```